# How do I define a new function `\juse`

Tags: macros, xetex, parameters

I want to define a new function `\juse` which takes 3 parameters and prints the second one.
However, this doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\juse{#1#2#3}{#2}
\begin{document}
$\juse{ abc }  {def} { ghi }$
\end{document}
```

It should print $def$ but gives an error.

Comment: The correct syntax for LaTeX would be `\newcommand\juse[3]{#2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a command in LaTeX that takes three mandatory arguments you'd only have to add a `[3]` to it. So a complete example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\juse[3]{#2}
\begin{document}
$\juse{ abc }  {def} { ghi }$
\end{document}
```

It is a bit unclear however, what you want to achieve with the command in a math enviroment, or if I got you wrong with the `$`'s.